# Magento 2.3.5 and 2.3.5-p1 versions

Tags: magento2.3, magento2.3.5, magento2.3.5-p1

I upgraded magento 2.3.4 to 2.3.5. But magento site https://magento.com/tech-resources/download is available version 2.3.5-p1? Something different with versions 2.3.5 and 2.3.5-p1?

Comment: have u take a look https://helpx.adobe.com/security/products/magento/apsb20-22.html

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell:

`Magento 2.3.5 Codebase` + `Security-Patches` => `Magento 2.3.5-p1 Codebase`